# flutter dropdown items from list - no instance method

Tags: flutter, dropdown, flutter-getx

i try to fill dropdown items. I am getting a json string from api and i save it with GetStorage.

I save like this.

```
box.write('itemsFromApi', listFromApi[0].myItems
```

and my string like below;

```
[{aaa: 2672366, bbb: 11312074, ccc: 1}, 
{aaa: 2672553, bbb: 11312015, ccc: 1}]
```

In my homepage

```
List _listx = [];

 @override
  void initState() {
    _listx = GetStorage().read('itemsFromApi');
}
```

And i try to fill dropdown items like below;
I am getting error **NoSuchMethodError (NoSuchMethodError: Class 'int' has no instance method 'where'.**

```
items: _listx[0]["ccc"]
              .where((p0) => p0.ccc== 1)
              .map(
                (item) => DropdownMenuItem<String>(
```

Answer (score 0):

you are trying to call where on integer _listx[0]["ccc"] you probably want to do _listx.where((p0) => p0.ccc== 1)

Comment: It throws error " NoSuchMethodError (NoSuchMethodError: Class '_InternalLinkedHashMap<String, dynamic>' has no instance getter 'ccc'.

Comment: As it’s currently written, your answer is unclear. Please [edit] to add additional details that will help others understand how this addresses the question asked. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).